# Is it ok to use a Pokémon name in my screen name? (stack, yt, github, etc.)

Tags: copyright

I use the screen name "AdamRaichu" on several platforms, including Stack Exchange, YouTube, GitHub, and others. I have been creating content on GitHub and using the name AdamRaichu in my licenses. Should I change my screen name to something that doesn't contain Raichu, or is it ok because I'm not doing creating content related to Pokémon or claiming to be sponsored by Nintendo?

Comment: That’s a very interesting question. I’ll read all the answers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Names in and of themselves are not subject to copyright.